# I am unable to import tensorflow and tflearn

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7SqU.png)

Here is my code:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import tensorflow
import numpy
import tflearn

import random
import json

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

Every module is successfully installed however `tflearn` and `tensorflow` are unable to import and every time cmd raises an import error

Comment: Does your CPU support AVX?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow release binaries (CPU/GPU) version 1.6 and higher are prebuilt with AVX instruction sets.
See hardware requirements to know more.

Therefore on any CPU that does not have these instruction sets, either CPU or GPU version of TF will fail to load.

Try using google's colab